# Inherit model to update hr.contract model in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

I would like to create a python class, which will update the wage field in the model hr.contract with values ​​contained in another model (ex: grillesalaire) already create

Many thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

In the python file, under the inherited hr.contract class

In write:

```
@api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
    if vals.get('wage'):
                self.field_you_want_to_pass = vals['wage']    
                        res = super(HrContract, self).write(vals)
```

In create:

```
@api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        res = super(HrContract, self).create(vals)           
            if vals.get('wage'):
                res.field_you_want_to_pass  = vals['wage']
```

Comment: Naveen, you can explain the function please I do not understand well. Who is vals,self and res